# search for the last two rows (by date) in Filemaker 19

Tags: filemaker

I have a Filemaker solution that stores measurement data. For a comparison report, I want to extract only the current and the previous rows of a specific set, and export them to XML.

I can easily search, filter and sort them, but how do I tell Filemaker to limit the resultset to a fixed number of rows?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The "last two rows" is one thing. The "current and the previous rows" is another. Please clarify **exactly** what do you want to happen.

Comment: The last or the first two rows in a sorted resultset (I don't care first/last because I can switch them around in the further processing if needed). Basically, if I have 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 9 then I want the 6 and the 9. (except that in my case I sort by date).

Comment: I believe my answer does exactly that. If you want the first 2 records instead of the last, then go to record #3 and omit from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script that reduces the current found set to the last two records. It is assumed that you have already performed a find and a sort. Then you can do simply:

```
Go to Record/Request/Page [ First ]
Omit Multiple Records [ Get ( FoundCount ) - 2 ] [ No dialog ]
```

Comment: sounds like exactly what I was looking for. I'll try it next time I touch that code

Comment: will do, just didn't try it yet.

Answer (score -2):

Add a selection field (selected=1 or unselected=0) and mark the last row and the previous row as selected, then do a search for selected field, export the elements you need, then mark all selection fields back to 0. All this executed from a simple script.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Record marking is unacceptable in a multi-user scenario, where each user needs to maintain their own selections, found sets, etc. Not to mention that the added complexity is unnecessary.